# Running sql in windows

Tags: sql-server, windows

Is running sql server on windows 7 good idea? I’m running a 10+ year old computer compaq

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what you want to do with it. If you just want to learn, then why not? However the most recent version of SQL server that is compatible is 2014 afaik. Mainstream support is no longer provided for that version. Likewise mainstream support has ceased for windows 7. So neither are suitable choices for a production environment.